# how to tell if a bigquery table is partially sorted

Tags: google-bigquery

We are clustering some of our big query tables and would like to know when we need to do some table maintenance based on how sorted the clustered column is . is there any way of telling how degraded the clustered sort is ? As online documentation suggests that  we may need to re cluster over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Are you deleting or updating data?
- Are you streaming data in?

My rules of thumb:

- Add data to a clustered table once a day, when the day is over.
- For updates and deletes use `MERGE`, as docs say it will force a reclustering.

BigQuery clustered tables are in beta, and I would expect BigQuery making smarter decisions by itself as the feature grows into maturity.